# Как можно получить регистр буквы,полученной с помощью `event.keyCode`?

Tags: javascript

Как можно получить регистр буквы,полученной с помощью `event.keyCode`?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я знаю с помощью `event.keyCode` - никак, нужно еще проверять `event.shiftKey`.

**UPD:** добавил обработку капслока

```js
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
    var upper = false;
    if (event.shiftKey)
      upper = true;
    if (event.originalEvent.getModifierState('CapsLock')) upper = !upper;
    upper ? alert('Верхний') : alert('Нижний');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ну так может быть и капс, может быть и скопированный текст

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть про капс согласен, не подумал. Скопированный текст вряд ли подходит к вопросу.

Comment: да, про скопированный я тоже не туда

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть поправил для капса